# The heartbeat has been running for ... which is longer than "00:00:01". This could be caused by thread pool starvation

Tags: .net-6.0, threadpool, azure-aks, linux-containers

This Warning is reported by an AKS job running a .NET 6.0 job in a Linux container.

The job is a background process performing heavy calculations on long numeric series.

It is not a web server but it is running a high number of parallel tasks. To make things faster, the chosed node size is one of the largest available (64 vCpu, 128 GiB). The machine is dedicated to this offline background calculation, so there are no issues of unresponsiveness or similar.

The event does not stop the process, but pops out periodically as a warning in the logs.
This is not a problem for the application, as it is exactly created to make lots of calculations in background, maximising the use of computation resources of the machine.

What I want to know is if I can safely ignore this message.

Comment: I think it should not be ignored as it indicates that a system limit has been reached. A similar issue has been solved here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46135. It was a memory leak issue.